# How Spit the required line from the given file & how i count that world

Tags: python, split, count, append, continue

Open the file `mbox-short.txt` and read it line by line. When you find a line that starts with `'From '` like the following line:

```
'From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'
```

You will parse the From line using `split()` and print out the second word in the line (i.e. the entire address of the person who sent the message). Then print out a count at the end.

You can download the sample data at http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt

I tried following:

```
fname = input('enter file name:')
fhand = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    if not line.startswith('from '):
         continue
    line = line.rstrip()
    spl = line.split()
    count = count+1
print spl[1]
```

Please tell me whats wrong with this.

Comment: Your `print` statement at the end isn't indented.

Comment: The problem is that Python is case sensitive. `'From' != 'from'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code had some minor issues, like indentation and typo. apart from that everything was perfect.

```
fname=input('enter file name:')
fhand=open(fname)
count=0
for line in fhand:
    if not line.startswith('From '): # change 'from' to 'From'
        continue
    line = line.rstrip()
    spl = line.split()
    count = count+1
    print(spl[1])  # Print every pattern matched, see it's within for loop

print("Total Persons:",count) # Print count
fhand.close()
```

Comment: jyotish, by this way each line printing twice.so how can we manage it.27 line required but in its program o/p 54 line printing..

Comment: change `line.startswith("From")` to `line.startswith("From ")`. I had updated the solution too to reflect the changes. Thanks!